Adding CC field to an Email template in Salesforce
I am creating a Record triggered flow in salesforce which sends out an email when a field in the Opportunity object is changed. I added an Action element, I select Email as action and specify the recipient ID and other necessary info. Now the email gets sent out to the contact related to the respective Opportunity. I am wondering if there is a way to include a CC and BCC field in the email template.
Please suggest me on how I can add CC and BCC fields to the email template.
